# how to focus a specific item in recycler view?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have 50 items in my recycler view. I want to focus or show specific item like when I click on button 1 it will focus items 10, and when I click on button 2 it will show/focus on items 30 and so on.

Comment: Use layoutmanager scrollToPosition

Answer (score 5):

You can use the RecyclerView directly for that.

Scroll to item:

- with animation

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(itemPosition)
```

- without animation

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(itemPosition)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for how to scroll to that 10th and 30th item then below solution is for you.

```
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(position)
```

Here `position` is, in which position you want to scroll.

For **highlight** that item you can change **text format like** **bold** or **color** of that item of recycler view.

Comment: If this is the solution that you were looking for then you can mark this answer as correct. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight a certain items, then pass another arraylist containing ids to be highlighted to your adapter. And create a function usually through an interface that updates that list and reloads all the items in a different manner. and for scroll use `smoothScrollToPosition(position)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
val itemPositionToFocus = 0 // for example the first item
val viewHolder = mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(itemPositionToFocus)
viewHolder.itemView.requestFocus()
```

Comment: Add a bit explanation of why and how this code works!